# How to activate a function on clicking a tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 2 tabs each of them displays different details. On clicking second tab, I have created a button clicking on which will display certain details. But would like to know if there are any method that calls the function directly when the tab is clicked.I tried activate function but it dint work.

```
        $(function() {
        $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
        activate: function( event, ui ) {
        fn.my_function(); }
        });
        });
```

Also I was wondering whether using activate function would be a good choice as the function is specific to second tab only.

Here is my code for the tabs :

```
      <div id="tabs">
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#tabs-1">DEMO</a></li>

      <li><a href="#tabs-2">Details 


      </a></li>
       </ul>
       <div id="tabs-1">

       <p><font color="blue"> Code </font>: Code number</p></br>
       <div id='popup-close'>Close</div>
       </div>

        <div id="tabs-2">
        <p></p>

          <input type="submit" name="call_function" id="call_function" value="Click for details"       />

             <table id='content'></table> // this is to display the details listed by the       function in the table format.
             <div id='popup-close1'>Close</div>
             </div>
```

Any pointers to solve this would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use the 'onclick' event on <a> tag like `<a href="#tabs-2" onclick="myFunction()">`

Comment: Which jQuery tabs plugin are you using? There will probably be a specific way to implement this for that particular plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you can trigger function for the specific tab by just adding an `id` to it:

```
<li><a id="tab1" href="#tabs-1">DEMO</a></li>

...

$("#tab1").click(...);
```

Another option is to write a proper [selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) to get first/second/n-th... `<li>` element:

```
$("#tabs ul li:nth-child(2)").click(...)
```